# Unable to load LVM module

Tags: linux, rhel, grub2, lvm, dracut

I am using RHEL 8, it was installed with Server with GUI, I need to change it to CLI (minimal) only so what I did from SSH session I ran following commands

```
yum group install "Minimal" -y 

yum group remove "Server with GUI" -y 

systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

I thought it will only remove GUI & other packages that is relevant to GUI only, so I reboot the machine & it stopped working, as per my experience it has remove lvm2 package & dependencies due to which at the startup lvm partitions are not recognized, here's the error that I get:

[image]

can't send text as I can't copy it from console, back to the point I tried to load the machine in rescue & emergency mode but it does not work & machine always landed to this dracut prompt:

[image]

I have tried to load lvm module but it does not work, any lead how can I recover my machine

Comment: Create a bootable Linux usb device and boot from there. The live cd will be able to mount your volumes. The chroot into it and install the packages you're missing. And don't put `-y` on your yum command line unless you know exactly what it will do.

Comment: @doneal24 thanks can you please recommend me some docs so I can check how to chroot from live usb

Comment: Many hits on a simple google search. One of the first ones that made sense was [here](https://opensource.com/article/22/9/recover-linux-system-live-usb). Note that the distro of the live image does not need to match your current OS. A Fedora image can be used to repair Debian, generic kernels to repair REL, etc.